# Probability that $5$ or $6$ are rolled $k$ times after $12$ rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Suppose you roll a fair dice $12$ times in a row. What is the probability of the event "exactly $k$ of the rolls are a $5$ or a $6$" ?

I'm just asking for some verification of my counting. Let $X$ be the random variable that counts the number of $5$ and $6$ rolled.

$$\begin{align}\displaystyle P(X=k)&=P\left((X=k)\bigcap \left(\bigcup_{i=0}^k \text{5 rolled $i$ times}\right)\right)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^kp\left((\text{5 rolled $i$ times})\cap (\text{6 rolled $k-i$ times}) \right)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{\binom{12}{i}\binom{12-i}{k-i}}{6^{12}}=\frac1{6^{12}}\binom{12}{k}2^k \end{align}$$

Is that right ? I think I'm supposed to find some Binomial distribution, so I must be wrong.

Comment: Nope.  You are almost right. (forgot to account for ways to roll not-5-or-6 12-k times)  $$\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{\binom{12}i\binom{12-i}{k-i}4^{12-k}}{6^{12}} = \frac {2^k 4^{12-k}}{6^{12}}\binom{12}k$$  You just took the *hard road* to find that: $X\sim \mathcal {Bin}(12, 2/6)$  See [barak manos](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/131263/barak-manos)' answer for the easy road.

Comment: @GrahamKemp yes, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability of "5" or "6" in a single roll is $\frac26$.

The result of each roll is independent of all the other rolls.

Hence the probability of exactly $k$ out of $12$ rolls giving "5" or "6" is:

$$\binom{12}{k}\cdot\left(\frac26\right)^{k}\cdot\left(1-\frac26\right)^{12-k}$$

Answer (score 3):

Solving this in your line (in order to expose your mistakes):

If $Y$ denotes the number of times that a $5$ is rolled and $Z$
denotes the number of times that a $6$ is rolled then:

$$P\left(Y+Z=k\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}P\left(Y=i\wedge Z=k-i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{12!}{i!\left(k-i\right)!\left(12-k\right)!}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{i}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{k-i}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{12-k}=\frac{4^{12-k}}{6^{12}}\binom{12}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}=\frac{4^{12-k}}{6^{12}}\binom{12}{k}2^{k}$$

Fortunately there is a better way (see the answer of Barak).